# const keyword and constant expressions in C99 and C11

Tags: c

Can we actually use const keyword in C99 and C11 to build constant expressions like this? What standard says about it?

```
const int n = 5;

int main()
{
   int arr[n];
}
```

In C89 / C90 we can't.

Comment: In case you have and `int` constant you can always define it as enumeration constant `enum { n = 5 };`. This then is an constant integral expression.

Answer (score 5):

No. `const` in C never means *constant* but it means ready-only.

This is the same for C90/C99/C11.

Note that in your example, you are using a variable length array. VLA have been introduced in C99 and the size of a VLA does not need to be a constant expression but still `n` is not a constant expression.

Comment: `n` is constant in that program.  There's no way around it.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, `const` does not make a constant like it does in C++.

On the other hand, C99 did add variable length arrays (VLAs), so for `auto` storage class, the size doesn't need to be a constant. This allows you to do things like:

```
int f(int n) { 
    int array[n];
    // ...
}
```

So, you can't do *exactly* what you're asking for, but you can do something that's close enough to equivalent for *many* (perhaps most) circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would likely use a macro to define the value of your constant.

The following is an example of what I mean by this.

```
#define N 5

int main() {
    int array[N];
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```