# How to Declare arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am still knew in learning c and i am facing the following problem.

I am trying to **initialize** and **declare** an array but it is giving me **compilation error**.

```
const   int a =2;
int x[a]={2};
```

Comment: use macro to define the constant size.

Comment: Please **always** mention the exact error you get.

Answer (score 5):

Variable length arrays cannot be initialized.

Assign the values after definition:

```
const int a = 2;
int x[a];
x[0] = 2;
```

Comment: @adminXVII No, `a` is not a constant, it is merely defined with const. `x` is a variable length array. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343027/const-keyword-and-constant-expressions-in-c99-and-c11, and C11 6.6 Constant expressions, and 6.2.5.Types paragraph 23

Comment: @adminXVII No problem. Don't forget to check the tags on questions.

Answer (score 1):

By using macro you can do that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define a 2
int main()
{
 int x[a]={2};
 //do something with array x
 return 0;
}
```